# Erro ao tentar implementar JTextArea na JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextarea

Estou tentando utilizar esse `JTextArea` em algumas colunas da minha `JTable`, mas está dando algo de errado. Sei que é errado, mas estou usando `DefaultTableModel`.

```
public class TextAreaCellRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
        public TextAreaCellRenderer() {
            setLineWrap(true);
            setWrapStyleWord(true);
            setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
            setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        }
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            // set color & border here              
            this.setText(value.toString());
            setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
            setSize(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth(),
                    getPreferredSize().height);
            if (table.getRowHeight(row) < getPreferredSize().height) {
                table.setRowHeight(row, getPreferredSize().height );
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
```

E estou usando assim pra chamar a classe

```
 jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaCellRenderer());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que está impedindo a execução desse código provavelmente é uma redundância que você adicionou pra evitar nullpointer, mas ao mesmo tempo manteve uma linha que precisava dessa verificação.

Como você está utilizando `DefaultTableModel`, geralmente ele inicia todo o model com valores nulos, e esses valores nulos preenchem as linhas da tabela. Mas na linha `this.setText(value.toString());` do seu renderer, você tenta converter o valor da célula sem checar se ela é nula, e logo abaixo você faz:

```
setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
```

Isso resolve o problema, mas você precisa remover a linha anterior mencionada, senão vai continuar estourando nullpointer.

Comment: Boa noite @Articuno, realmente era esse o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda! Eu tenho mais uma duvida. se vc testar essa classe em uma coluna e escrever bastante conteúdo, ela aumenta a célula perfeitamente, mas se vc observar, ele sempre escreve em linha reta e vc acaba não vendo oque escreveu para traz. gostaria de saber se é possível, ao chegar no limite da coluna, ele da uma quebra de linha, ou então dar um enter e ele dar a quebra.

Comment: @RafaelChaves o TableCellRenderer, como o proprio nome já diz, só serve para "renderizar" o conteudo da celula da tabela. Se você está escrevendo, você está editando a celular e não renderizando ela apenas. Provavelmente isso se resolve se implementar tambem um TableCellEditor nessa coluna, pois o padrão é que seja exibido um JTextField quando entra em modo de edição, você precisaria implementar a classe citada para que seja exibido também uma textarea  em modo de edição.

Comment: Entendido. você teria um exemplo de como posso resolver esse problema? as pessoas vão digitar textos corridos e as vezes tópico.. para isso a necessidade da quebra de linha. eu iri te agradecer demais da conta.

Comment: resolvi o problema aqui. criei um celleditor e deu tudo certo. obrigado mesmo pela dica! Unico problema que estou tendo é que minha celula onde coloquei o 'TextAreaCellRenderer ' não está recebendo foco.